# Raising a polymer event from the outside

Tags: javascript, jquery, polymer, web-component

I have a very simple polymer element, something in lines of this:

```
<polymer-element name="pictures-list">
<template>
    <h2>
        <span id="pictitle">{{pictures.title}}</span>
    </h2>
    <input type="button" class="btn-hello" onclick="alert('hello');" value="Say Hello" />
    <paper-button class="btn-paper-hello" on-tap="{{tap}}" >flat button</paper-button>
</template>
<script>
    Polymer({
        tap: function() {
            console.log("tapped");
            this.$.pictitle.textContent = "Test"
        }
    });
</script>
</polymer-element>
```

And here's how it is hosted:

```
<body unresolved>
<div class="container">
    <pictures-list></pictures-list>
</div>
</body>
```

What I want to achieve is to somehow raise the click/tap event from the outside (for the purpose of testing my component. Due to ShadowDOM, you can not directly access the elements, but you could write a selector like this, to get to the input or paper-button element:

```
$("body > .container /deep/ .btn-hello")
```

or

```
$("body > .container /deep/ .btn-paper-hello")
```

Now, I can just execute the click function on the input (the html button), and it'd execute the click handler (showing the alert) like this:

```
$("body > .container /deep/ .btn-hello").click();
```

I want to do basically the same thing, but for paper-button. It'd work if I use the click event on paper-button, but not on-tap. So these do not work:

```
$("body > .container /deep/ .btn-paper-hello").tap();
```

this one doesn't work either:

```
$("body > .container /deep/ .btn-paper-hello").ontap();
```

My question is, how do I do that? I can execute fire function, giving it the name of the event, which would give me a CustomeEvent object back, but still, it is not executed, e.g.:

```
$("body > .container /deep/ .btn-paper-hello").fire("on-tap")
```

Comment: I think you want to fire('tap')

Comment: @robdodson I don't know how on earth I missed that :) thanks!!

Comment: So, `.fire('tap')` doesn't work for me. Could still use an answer on how to fire this event.